# How can i use variable inside template literals?

Tags: javascript, html, web

Here is my code, and the problem is with variable `unosAutor`.
I need to check if two strings are same with helper equal, but how to use variable `unosAutor` in template literals.
When i put "some text" instead of `unosAutor` it works.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>2 kolokvijum</title>
</head>
<body>
    Unesite ime autora: <input id="imeAutora" type="text" placeholder="Ime autora"><br><br>
    <button id="btnAutor" type="submit" onClick="proveraAutora()">Prikazi</button><br><br>
    <div id="sadrzaj"></div>

    <script src="js/handlebars-v4.0.11.js"></script>
    <script src="js/qwest.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function proveraAutora(){
            var unosAutor = document.querySelector("#imeAutora").value;
            var knjigeTemplate = 
            `
                {{#each knjige}}
                {{#equal autor unosAutor}}
                    <h2>{{naslov}} {{autor}}</h2>
                    <img src="{{slika}}"></img>
                    <h4>Broj strana: {{brojstrana}}</h4>
                    <h4><b>Cena: </b>{{cena}}</h4>
                {{/equal}}
                {{/each}}
            `;

            var divSadrzaj = document.querySelector("#sadrzaj");

            qwest.get('data/json.json').then(function(xhr, response){
                var Render = Handlebars.compile(knjigeTemplate);
                divSadrzaj.innerHTML = Render({knjige : response});
            });

        };  
        Handlebars.registerHelper('equal', function(lvalue, rvalue, options) {
            if (arguments.length < 3)
                throw new Error("Handlebars Helper equal needs 2 parameters");
            if (lvalue != rvalue) {
            return options.inverse(this);
            } else {
                return options.fn(this);
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [normal syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) `${unosAutor}`

If you are using equal helper in handle bars you may have to include quotes. `"${unosAutor}"`, so that you get the result as `{{#equal autor "AutorX"}}`

```js
var unosAutor = 'AutorX'
var knjigeTemplate =
  `
                {{#each knjige}}
                {{#equal autor "${unosAutor}"}}
                    <h2>{{naslov}} {{autor}}</h2>
                    <img src="{{slika}}"></img>
                    <h4>Broj strana: {{brojstrana}}</h4>
                    <h4><b>Cena: </b>{{cena}}</h4>
                {{/equal}}
                {{/each}}
            `;
console.log(knjigeTemplate)
```

Comment: Yes i tried this but it doesent work. Dont know where is problem :/

Comment: If you are using equal helper in handle bars you may have to include quotes. `"${unosAutor}"`. Check the updated answer

Answer (score 0):

To use variables in template literals, use `${yourVariable}` like this:

```js
var variable = "some text";

console.log(`The value of variable is: ${variable}`);
```

And in your case:

```js
var unosAutor = 'some text'
var knjigeTemplate =
  `
                {{#each knjige}}
                {{#equal autor ${unosAutor}}}
                    <h2>{{naslov}} {{autor}}</h2>
                    <img src="{{slika}}"></img>
                    <h4>Broj strana: {{brojstrana}}</h4>
                    <h4><b>Cena: </b>{{cena}}</h4>
                {{/equal}}
                {{/each}}
            `;
console.log(knjigeTemplate)
```